# How to change date format using SQL?

Tags: sqlite

I have column with strings of dates with format: "dd.mm.yyyy". 
I need to convert the date format contained in the strings to ISO8601 format: "YYYY-MM-DD" for the whole column.

Comment: *I have column with strings of dates* Does this mean the field is defined as varchar? If so use strftime() function for to parse datetime using your current format.

Comment: I use data type TEXT to store dates (in SQLite). I think it looks like a data type varchar.

Comment: if so `strftime()` must solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String manipulation seems to way to go here:

```
UPDATE myTable
  SET myDate = SUBSTR(myDate, 7, 4)
     || '-' || SUBSTR(myDate, 4, 2)
     || '-' || SUBSTR(myDate, 1, 2)
```